# systemd service

Tags: systemd, sysvinit, systemd-unit, runlevel

I'm wondering how services launched by means of ***systemd*** working. 
When system was running by means of System V init, there was scripts under *runlevels* (**/etc/rc"level".d/**)  which described exactly what should be performed. 
Under systemd, there's not too much information. 
For example, there's a script under /etc/rc5.d which used for launching cups server and there's some more than 90 lines. 
From the other hand, if we look in cups.service (under /lib/systemd/system) there're only these lines :

**

```
[Unit]
Description=CUPS Scheduler
Documentation=man:cupsd(8)
After=network.target nss-user-lookup.target nslcd.service
Requires=cups.socket
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cupsd -l
Type=notify
Restart=on-failure
[Install]
Also=cups.socket cups.path
WantedBy=printer.target multi-user.target
```

**

It's very different from previous approach, thus I don't understand how it runs

Comment: Have you checked on available documentation such as [systemd.io](https://systemd.io/)? One of the major driving forces is that SysV init is sequential while systemd is parallel, resulting (hopefully) in faster boot times.

Comment: Hi @doneal24 , Thanks for the answer , but actually I've asked something different

Comment: It might be more appropriate to ask "why does the svsV cups service need more than 90 lines"?  You can see this service simply calls `cupsd`.  Its logging is built into systemd (thus no need for any scripting) and process monitoring/restart logic is defined by only two lines (this would require more if implemented in a shell).  Also see the associated socket and path units.  Those set up file-descriptors for cupsd which can also eliminate lots of scripting.